# Square bracket or dot notation in SCIM filters for multivalued complex attributes?

Tags: scim, scim2

I'm implementing a SCIM service provider at the moment and noticed some examples on the internet use the square-bracket form when filtering a multivalued list of complex values, while others use the dot notation form.

I see `emails[value eq 'foo@bar.com']` being used interchangeably with `emails.value eq foo@bar.com`.

Obviously the square-bracket form allows for more filter conditions and the latter is more a shorthand.

Is the dot-notation form required to be supported when filtering a multivalued attribute on the properties of its complex children?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RFC 7644 section 3.4.2.2, Figure 2 (right above [this section](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7644#section-3.4.2.3)) has some examples of valid filters. Among those, `emails.value co "example.org"` is mentioned as a valid example. If you're building a SCIM service provider, then this is definitely a valid use case to consider supporting in your implementation.

However, in my experience, when it comes to SCIM filters, I mainly see the dot operator being used to reference a sub-attribute of complex attributes like `name.familyName`. I haven't seen very many usages of dot operators for multi-valued attributes like `emails.value` in a filter. So I'm not sure how often this is really used in practice, but I would generally encourage SCIM clients to use the square bracket formation.

Comment: Thanks, this is kind of what I thought. I guess I'll have to support the dot syntax for multivalued attributes since we want to not be "special" when users use examples from the RFC. It's a pain though, the square bracket syntax is clearly the Right Way.